# Handling per-user settings in Visual Studio projects (C++)

Tags: c++, visual-studio, visual-studio-2012, visual-studio-2013

What is the recommended way of handling per-user settings in C++ Visual Studio projects? For example, different developers may store libraries at different locations and so each of them would set Include Directories differently. How can I extract those settings to a file which will not need to be committed to a source control?

According to [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/669zx6zc.aspx), use of global `.user` Property Sheets is discouraged. However, per-project Property Sheets seem to still be part of their projects and, at least as far as I can tell, they need to be committed to the source control. Is there a way to make them so that they will not need to be committed? What other alternatives to the deprecated global properties do I have?

Comment: Working with [property files (`.props`)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/669zx6zc.aspx)?

Comment: Aren't those property sheets I mentioned? But as far as I know they need to be versioned so they will be the same for everyone working on the project. Unless everyone will remember not to commit their versions which looks ugly to me. I checked what happens if a `.prop` file is missing and the project did not load so the file cannot be added to an ignore list.

Comment: At work we use CMake to generate our Visual Studio project and build out of source. Any settings will be in the build tree and this is not included at all in the source control nor are any other generated files like Visual Studio project files which CMake generates..

Comment: We use VMs created by DevOps tools for development at work, so every developer has an identical, easily reproducible and maintainable work environment.